# Parsing XML feed into Ruby object using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, nokogiri

I am pretty green with coding in Ruby but am trying to pull an XML feed into a Ruby object:

```
<% doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://api.workflowmax.com/job.api/current?apiKey=#{@feed.service.api_key}&accountKey=#{@feed.service.account_key}")) %>

<% doc.xpath('//Jobs/Job').each do |node| %>
    <h2><%= node['name'].text %></h2>
    <p><%= node['description'].text %></p>
<% end %>
```

Basically, I want to iterate through each `Job` and output the name, description etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest separating logic and presentation. You should have your XMl parsing in the Controller. You also should make it asyn, since you dont know how long the feed requesting/parsing going to take.

Other than that what problem do you get? An error of some kind? Empty page?

Comment: What happens if you replace .text with .content? Otherwise being able to see a sample of the XML would help a bit too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since you haven't shown us any sample XML, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it is not likely the description is in an attribute. You've used the syntax to extract 'name' and 'description' attributes from the 'job' element. If instead they are nested elements you want something like this:

```
<% doc.xpath('//Jobs/Job').each do |node| %>
    <h2><%= node.xpath('name').inner_text %></h2>
    <p><%= node.xpath('description').inner_text %></p>
<% end %>
```